# Getting android debuggable default value for release build true

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest, android-debug

I have not set attribute debuggable in AndroidManifest nor in build gradle. Niether any of library I used in my project does not use this attribute.

As default value for attribute debuggable is false. However, I am getting debuggable true in AndroidManifest by reverse engineering team. How it can be track down. Where I am missing?

Comment: can you please post your `build.gradle` file and `AndroidManifest.xml` file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a quick check as follows:

If you want to check whether the signed release `apk` is debuggable use the below `aapt command`.

```
aapt dump badging /path/to/apk | grep -c application-debuggable
```

Outputs 1: Debuggable Outputs 0: Not Debuggable.

If your `apk` if found to be `debuggable` using `aapt` then you might need to try explicitly mentioning `android:debuggable=false` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

or,

Do a deep dive of all the dependencies in your project, check whether `debuggable` is getting set from any where else.

Hope that helps.